# Flash CS4/AS3 Dynamic Text Box

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have created a XML image gallery, which displays text in between each slide. Now I have created a movie clip with a dynamic text field (with Render HTML selected) to display the text from the XML which is pushed into an array. Now, this all works great BUT... /n or /r is not creating a new line break (as they need to be custom). Yet if I create an Array and manually push strings "Bla bla bla /n bla bla bla" I get a line break. I have tried converting the Array item to string (even though it already is), I would also avoid creating textField = new textField() any Ideas would be welcomed.

Cheers

Comment: Can you show your XML, and the trace of the xml before setting it to your textfield

Comment: XML node is like this:
<image imageFile="GrandOpening1.jpg" text="XXXXX \nXXXXXX\nXXXX XXXX XXXXXX"></image>

trace of the .@text = XXXXX \nXXXXXX\nXXXX XXXX XXXXXX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your TextField is HTML enabled, it would be better to use a `<br>` tag to create a new line break.

Comment: If I use <br> in xml it gives me 
TypeError: Error #1095: XML parser failure: Unterminated attribute.

Comment: Just put your text in a <![CDATA[ ... ]]> block inside your XML, so the tags used inside are not processed by the XML parser. ( http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_cdata.asp )

Comment: Nailed it, taking the text out of the attribute and nesting it in the node with CData works. Tres Bon @Zed-K

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

You have two choices :

-as suggested put replace in your XML the `\n` by a `<br/>` but encoded to be a valid XML  `&lt;br/&gt;`

```
<image imageFile="GrandOpening1.jpg"
       text="XXXXX&lt;br/&lt;XXXXXX&lt;br/&lt;XXXX XXXX XXXXXX">
</image>
```

-or at runtime when filling your textfield replace the `\n` by a `<br/>`

```
myTextField.htmlText=xml.@text.toString().split("\\n").join("<br/>");
```

---

`/n /r` is not correct it 's `\n \r`.

Have you enable multiline option for your TextField.

Comment: Yeah, sorry...I meant /n and yes Multiline is enabled

Answer (score 0):

\n \r only works in runtime and 
 won't work. 
I use a custom string to represent linebreak "#BR#" for example. Before you pass the string to the text box, replace all instances of "#BR#" with "\n" using regular expression.

var str:String = xmlString;
var pattern:RegExp = /#BR#/ig;//target all instances of #BR#(case insensitive)
txt_textbox.text=str.replace(pattern, "\n");